# Quick sort algorithm in Rust

Tags: rust, quick-sort

I have written this Rust code to implement the quick sort algorithm. Could you review it and tell me if it is idiomatic or not? Especially about my use of the slices?

````rust
fn quick_sort<T: Ord>(array: &mut [T]) {
    let n = array.len();
    if n > 0 {
        let mut i_pivot = 0;
        for i in 1..n {
            if &array[i] < &array[n - 1] {
                array.swap(i, i_pivot);
                i_pivot += 1;
            }
        }
        array.swap(i_pivot, n - 1);
        quick_sort(&mut array[0..i_pivot]);
        quick_sort(&mut array[i_pivot + 1..n]);
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Fixed-size array (type signature is superfluous)
    let mut xs = [
        8, 13, 20, 13, 4, 21, 24, 13, 18, 23, 14, 6, 10, 2, 4, 6, 16, 6, 17, 9, 8, 20, 14, 19, 7,
        9, 18, 0, 18, 1, 8, 10,
    ];

    quick_sort(&mut xs);

    println!("{:?}", xs);
}
```
````

Comment: (Positive you want to sort arrays of len 1 recursively?)

Comment: Oh, right, it would be better with `if n > 1` ! Thanks @greybeard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code review:
1. Your code has a bug here `for i in 1..n`,
the correct version starts from **zero**: `for i in 0..n`,
Change your main to the following code and then `cargo run`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut xs = vec![
        8, 13, 20, 13, 4, 21, 24, 13, 18, 23, 14, 6, 10, 2, 4, 6, 16, 6, 17, 9, 8, 20, 14, 19, 7,
        9, 18, 0, 18, 1, 8, 10,
    ];
    let mut v = xs.clone();
    v.sort();
    quick_sort(&mut xs);
    assert_eq!(v, xs);
}
```

You will see this error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `[0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 16, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 21, 23, 24]`,
 right: `[0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 4, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 8, 13, 13, 14, 14, 16, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 13, 23, 24, 21]`', src/main.rs:25:5
```

2. Rename `i_pivot` to `j`, since it is just an index and your pivot is `a[n - 1]`.
3. Change `if n > 0` to `if n > 1` since the slice length should be at least **two**.
4. You don't need `Ord` here, [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html) is enough ([try it here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7ad1c81d319d1c3c4d5a2715f3d75569)):

```
fn quick_sort<T: PartialOrd>(a: &mut [T]) {
    let n = a.len();
    if n > 1 {
        let mut j = 0;
        for i in 0..n {
            if &a[i] < &a[n - 1] {
                a.swap(i, j);
                j += 1;
            }
        }
        a.swap(j, n - 1); // pivot
        quick_sort(&mut a[0..j]);
        quick_sort(&mut a[j + 1..n]);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut xs = vec![
        8, 13, 20, 13, 4, 21, 24, 13, 18, 23, 14, 6, 10, 2, 4, 6, 16, 6, 17, 9, 8, 20, 14, 19, 7,
        9, 18, 0, 18, 1, 8, 10,
    ];
    let mut v = xs.clone();
    v.sort();
    quick_sort(&mut xs);
    assert_eq!(v, xs);
}
```